# Telegram new version- send poll API

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf-plugins

I'm developing bot using telegram API and node (using telegraf repo).
All the users that use Telegram's new version (V6.1.0) have the following bug:

[image: bug - no vote button.]

As you can see- the **'vote'** button is missing. Anyone knows this bug? 
I checked and in groups the vote does appear, but in 1 on 1 chat its missing.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The vote button shows only when you have a multi-answer poll.
you can enable it in the send poll panel > Multiple Answer. then you can see the button under the poll.